# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 when using Tesseract

Tags: ios, xcode, tesseract, arm64

I am using tesseract provided by google. After following [this](https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS) tutorial, i finally built finish my app. However, when i run it, i run into the problem of undefined symbols. This is the error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_G8Tesseract", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How do i fix this issue? I tried searching online but none of the solutions worked for me. I tried reinstalling the pods and updating it. Then i faced this error

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/admin/Desktop/tst/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-tst/Pods-tst-dummy.m'
clang: error: no input files
```

When i tried redoing the project i get his error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_G8Tesseract", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You have some problem in : Pods-tst-dummy.m please check this forst.

Comment: What recent changes you made to your project??

Comment: I can't find my Pods-tst-dummy.m. And what do you mean by recent changes. I just followed the steps from that website

Comment: Try : pod update --verbose

Comment: thanks you it helped first the first error. However now `ld: library not found for -lPods-test` this error shows up

Comment: Ok then run this first: sudo gem install cocoapods and then again  pod update --verbose

Answer (score 1):

Apparently i had to add the TesseractOCR.framework separately even after using cocoa pods and disable Bitcode. This prevented the errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should update pod version:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

After this run:

```
pod update --verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Tesseract requires libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib (or libstdc++.6.0.9.tbd if libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib is unavailable in your current Xcode version) and CoreImage.framework you’ll need to link both of these libraries in.

In the General tab, scroll down to Linked Frameworks and Libraries.

[image]

There should be only one file here: TesseractOCR.framework, which you just added. Click the + button underneath the list. Find both libstdc++.dylib (or libstdc++.6.0.9.tbd) and CoreImage.framework and add them to your project.

[image]